# Trim string in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

I like to trim following string but there is an error:

```
var getClients = (from c in GeneralUtillities)
    orderby c.Client_Name
    select new
    {
        c.Client_Name.Trim(),
        c.Client_Code,
    });
```

Thnx

Answer (score 8):

You need to provide names for the Anonymous type object properties

```
var getClients = (from c in GeneralUtillities)
    orderby c.Client_Name
    select new
    {
        Name = c.Client_Name.Trim(),
        Client_Code = c.Client_Code
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't provide a name in an anonymous type property, it attempts to use the property name of the value it's being assigned. As you've invoked a method on the property, it can't resolve the name. You need to specify it:

```
var getClients = (from c in GeneralUtillities)
orderby c.Client_Name
select new
{
    Client_Name = c.Client_Name.Trim(),
    c.Client_Code,
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I see 3 things - since you didn't specify the error I'm not certain what the true problem is, but here are some guesses:

1. You've got a closing paren at the end of `GeneralUtillities` which is a syntax error
2. You don't specify a name for the first field in the anonymous type
3. Linq-to-Entities may not support the use of `Trim`

Here's an alternative:

```
var getClients = (from c in GeneralUtillities
    orderby c.Client_Name)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select (c =>  new
        {
            Client_Name = c.Client_Name.Trim(),
            Client_Code = c.Client_Code,  // for readability, not necessary
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the property of an anonymous type must be known at compile time.

```
var getClients = (from c in GeneralUtillities)
    orderby c.Client_Name
    select new
    {
        Name= c.Client_Name.Trim(),
        Code = c.Client_Code,
    });
```

Comment: Ok what is Name and Code some global variables!? I want next getClient to sent to grid

Comment: what do you mean? you can set column name for your `datagridview` and pass `getClients` for its `Datasource`

Comment: but you should disable `AutoGenerateColumns` of your gridview Then only define the columns you want to show

Answer (score -1):

```
var getClients =
    (from c in GeneralUtillities.a.data
    orderby c.Client_Name
    select new
    {
        c.ID_Client,
        c.Client_Name,
    });
```

This is right code, so the problem is to trim Client Name to have no space in start and end.